# Setting machine wide environment variable in Nano server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, nano-server

I started a remote session from VM host(desktop) to the guest VM having a Nano server(preview 5). I would like to update the PATH variable and make it effect machine wide(example: to put `dotnet.exe` in PATH to enable running portable apps). What I am noticing is that the `SetEnvironmentVariable` overload doesn't have the overload which takes in the target(like 'User', 'Machine' etc.).

If you notice I have the overload in my host's Powershell (the version is a bit older than the Nano server one) but not on the Nano server's one.

**In my Nano server:**
[image]

**In my VM host(desktop)**
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Nano server uses a stripped down version of .NET called .NET Core. (More info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694084.aspx).)

The documentation for the Core implementation of `SetEnvironmentVariable` is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-1.1).

**EDIT 26 Sept 2017:**

This answer applied to .NET Core 1.x. In .NET Core 2.0, the overload the OP was looking for has been added. The documentation for 2.0 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-2.0).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command setx to set the environment variables

Comment: Setting variable with setx works just fine, but setx does not allow to remove a variable. At least the Microsoft recommended way (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195050) did not work for me, I got "invalid syntax" error. I had to use PowerShell: `Remove-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name CATALINA_HOME`